# How to get total increments in Disp subroutine in ABAQUS

Tags: fortran, subroutine, abaqus

I am using Disp subroutine in ABAQUS. I want to apply a specific boundary condition to my model. This a part of my code:

```
  IF (NODE==mst(2,1)) THEN
     IF (JDOF .EQ. 1) THEN
       U(1)=0.01
     ELSE IF (JDOF .EQ. 2) THEN
       U(1)=0
     ELSE
       U(1)=0
     END IF
  END IF
```

The problem is that I do not know how many incerement does ABAQUS use to solve the model. Thus, I do not know how to change the value of "U(1)=0.01" to its incremental. I know that "KINC" gives the current increment number. However, I do not know how to get the total number of increments. Morover, is there any need to change the value to incremental or ABAQUS would do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The total number of increments is not known a priori unless you specify it (i.e. if it has troubles converging, it will decrease the step size and thus increase the step number). You can use TIME(1) and TIME(2) to know the current value of step time and reformulate your load based on that, which I think is what you're looking for.

For the second question, Abaqus will compute the increment automatically or follow a specified depending on the solver settings you prescribe. There are some user subroutines that can control the increment size but DISP is not one of them.

Comment: Dear Miguel, Thanks for your response. My question is: "I need to set the final value of U_x(1) to 0.01. In the case that the ABAQUS needs more than one increment to solve my simulation, how can I change the value of U_x(1) to its incremental value? Or ABAQUS will do it automatically and it will understand that U_x(1)=0.01 is the final value?"

Comment: U(1) is the total value of the prescribed variable at this point. So if the displacement varies from zero to your amplitude, you can just make it proportional to the current step time TIME(1). U(...) = 0.01 * TIME(1) This means that for step time = 1, your point will have displacement 0.01, increasing linearly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Would you please tell me about whether or not I should change the value of U(1) in DISP to its incremental value?If ABAQUS needs more than one increment to do this simulation, at each increment it tries to apply the final value of the U(1)?

Comment: It should be the total value and not the increment. If it needs more increments it'll call your subroutine with the appropriate time step.